# Is it save to change Site Column(choice) values?

Tags: site-column

I have a site collection with site column (text choices). This column is used on multiple subsites. Few years ago I created a webpart to allow users to add new choices to this column (they don't have access to the root site, so I created a new webpart that runs with elevated privileges).

All works, but now users want to change some deprecated existing values in this column. I'm not sure that this would be safe and does not break already existing values.

Another problem is that this column is already used in third-party solutions, so it is hard to migrate to lookup field. What do you think? Maybe you've had the same problem before (update existing choices)?

Comment: AFAIK, Choice column is saved as Text in the backend, and it will have no effect if you delete existing values and there are still records which have them. Of course the deleted values will not appear on the new item form. So you are all safe!

Comment: That above is my experience also.

Comment: Thank You much for responses, guys! Then I'll modify my webpart and allow users to change values